# What's the path to global node_modules folder in Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci, node-modules

I need to pass the path for the `node_modules` global installation folder to the `mink-zombie-driver`, but I can't find anywhere in the docs what's the path for it.

[MinkExtension](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/doc/index.rst#drivers) requires you to pass the `node_modules` folder in the configuration file for Behat.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/775?